# vb 2008 Run Grayed Out-on

Tags: vb.net

My Run button is grayed out. This includes starting a new project of any type.
I completely un-installed VS 2008 and Re-Installed it. The Run is Still grayed out.
VB is now worthless.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your project has a starting point.  
Go to your project properties, under the "Application" tab, see if "Startup form" is set correctly.

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbide/thread/27510bb8-1a82-479a-aad1-429c29724ea3)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you take this problem to MS Support or the MSDN forums.